# Debian testing/bookworm user can not login using GNOME Shell 41.4 after upgrade

Tags: debian, gnome, login, gui, testing

After applying a recent upgrade on my Debian-System, I can not login in with my user Account. The password is not recognized. Logging in without GUI using the same user and password works fine.

```
Operating System: Debian GNU/Linux bookworm/sid
          Kernel: Linux 5.16.0-5-686-pae
    Architecture: x86
 Hardware Vendor: Lenovo
  Hardware Model: Rev 1.
     Gnome-shell: 41.4
```

**Does anyone know how to fix this?**

*I got `apt-listbugs` installed and did not get any warning, before applying the upgrade.*

Comment: Same error here. GUI login borked after update on bookworm. VirtualBox VM on Windows Lenovo host.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**[FIXED]** - The login with the Gnome GUI is working again on `Debian GNU/Linux bookworm/sid` since Linux Kernel-Version: `5.16.0-6-686-pae` and `GNOME Shell 42.0`

Answer (score 1):

I think it's not a password not recognized problem, in my case there is an exception when loading main.js of gnome-shell. Looks like API in glib changed:  glib.timezone.get_offset at least 1 argument required.
Probably gnome-shell needs to be also updated to 42.0.

Answer (score 0):

Debian_user may be right, dropping gnome-weather removes the libgweather libraries, in debian testing some gnome packages are from the old gnome-shell version and some new ones, for libgweather from version 3.x to version 4.0 API changed which may cause problems:

https://gnome.pages.gitlab.gnome.org/libgweather/migrating-3to4.html

and:

https://www.mail-archive.com/debian-bugs-dist@lists.debian.org/msg1849602.html

in debian testing actually:

gnome-weather is in 42.0-1 version and requires gir1.2-gweather-4.0

but

gnome-shell is in version 41.4-1 and requires gir1.2-gweather-3.0

and install newer version of gir1.2-gweather crash gnome-shell.

I have not tested but suspect there is a problem here

Answer (score -2):

Remove gnome-weather package and gnome-shell login will work again.

Comment: Welcome to the site, and thank you for your contribution. However, please note that it remains unclear why removing a seemingly unrelated package will make the GNOME login work again. Perhaps you could add some explanation, and possibly a link to an external reference where this effect is investigated.

Comment: This does not work!